# Using PCL in ROS2 eloquent can't pass the compilation

Tags: ros2, pcl

When I add  "ament_target_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_featureExtraction "PCL")" to the CMakeLists it shows

```
Cannot get compiler information 
Compiler exited with error code 1/usr/bin/c++ -xc++ -D -DDISABLE_DAVIDSDK -DDISABLE_DSSDK -DDISABLE_ENSENSO -DDISABLE_LIBUSB_1_0 -DDISABLE_PCAP -DDISABLE_PNG -DDISABLE_RSSDK -DFLANN_STATIC -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DROSCONSOLE_BACKEND_LOG4CXX -DROS_PACKAGE_NAME=\"lio_sam\" -Dqh_QHpointer -DvtkFiltersFlowPaths_AUTOINIT=1(vtkFiltersParallelFlowPaths) -DvtkIOExodus_AUTOINIT=1(vtkIOParallelExodus) -DvtkIOGeometry_AUTOINIT=1(vtkIOMPIParallel) -DvtkIOImage_AUTOINIT=1(vtkIOMPIImage) -DvtkIOParallel_AUTOINIT=1(vtkIOMPIParallel) -DvtkIOSQL_AUTOINIT=2(vtkIOMySQL,vtkIOPostgreSQL) -DvtkRenderingContext2D_AUTOINIT=1(vtkRenderingContextOpenGL) -DvtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT=3(vtkInteractionStyle,vtkRenderingFreeType,vtkRenderingOpenGL) -DvtkRenderingFreeType_AUTOINIT=2(vtkRenderingFreeTypeFontConfig,vtkRenderingMatplotlib) -DvtkRenderingLIC_AUTOINIT=1(vtkRenderingParallelLIC) -DvtkRenderingVolume_AUTOINIT=1(vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL) -isystem/usr/local/include/opencv4 -isystem/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -isystem/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -g -fPIC -fpch-preprocess -v -dD -E
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/c++
    OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
    OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
    Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
    Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-D' '-DDISABLE_DAVIDSDK' '-D' 'DISABLE_DSSDK' '-D' 'DISABLE_ENSENSO' '-D' 'DISABLE_LIBUSB_1_0' '-D' 'DISABLE_PCAP' '-D' 'DISABLE_PNG' '-D' 'DISABLE_RSSDK' '-D' 'FLANN_STATIC' '-D' 'QT_CORE_LIB' '-D' 'QT_GUI_LIB' '-D' 'QT_WIDGETS_LIB' '-D' 'ROSCONSOLE_BACKEND_LOG4CXX' '-D' 'ROS_PACKAGE_NAME="lio_sam"' '-D' 'qh_QHpointer' '-D' 'vtkFiltersFlowPaths_AUTOINIT=1(vtkFiltersParallelFlowPaths)' '-D' 'vtkIOExodus_AUTOINIT=1(vtkIOParallelExodus)' '-D' 'vtkIOGeometry_AUTOINIT=1(vtkIOMPIParallel)' '-D' 'vtkIOImage_AUTOINIT=1(vtkIOMPIImage)' '-D' 'vtkIOParallel_AUTOINIT=1(vtkIOMPIParallel)' '-D' 'vtkIOSQL_AUTOINIT=2(vtkIOMySQL,vtkIOPostgreSQL)' '-D' 'vtkRenderingContext2D_AUTOINIT=1(vtkRenderingContextOpenGL)' '-D' 'vtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT=3(vtkInteractionStyle,vtkRenderingFreeType,vtkRenderingOpenGL)' '-D' 'vtkRenderingFreeType_AUTOINIT=2(vtkRenderingFreeTypeFontConfig,vtkRenderingMatplotlib)' '-D' 'vtkRenderingLIC_AUTOINIT=1(vtkRenderingParallelLIC)' '-D' 'vtkRenderingVolume_AUTOINIT=1(vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL)' '-isystem' '/usr/local/include/opencv4' '-isystem' '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5' '-isystem' '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets' '-isystem' '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui' '-isystem' '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore' '-isystem' '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++' '-g' '-fPIC' '-fpch-preprocess' '-v' '-dD' '-E' '-D' '___CIDR_DEFINITIONS_END' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1plus -E -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE -D -DDISABLE_DAVIDSDK -D DISABLE_DSSDK -D DISABLE_ENSENSO -D DISABLE_LIBUSB_1_0 -D DISABLE_PCAP -D DISABLE_PNG -D DISABLE_RSSDK -D FLANN_STATIC -D QT_CORE_LIB -D QT_GUI_LIB -D QT_WIDGETS_LIB -D ROSCONSOLE_BACKEND_LOG4CXX -D ROS_PACKAGE_NAME="lio_sam" -D qh_QHpointer -D vtkFiltersFlowPaths_AUTOINIT=1(vtkFiltersParallelFlowPaths) -D vtkIOExodus_AUTOINIT=1(vtkIOParallelExodus) -D vtkIOGeometry_AUTOINIT=1(vtkIOMPIParallel) -D vtkIOImage_AUTOINIT=1(vtkIOMPIImage) -D vtkIOParallel_AUTOINIT=1(vtkIOMPIParallel) -D vtkIOSQL_AUTOINIT=2(vtkIOMySQL,vtkIOPostgreSQL) -D vtkRenderingContext2D_AUTOINIT=1(vtkRenderingContextOpenGL) -D vtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT=3(vtkInteractionStyle,vtkRenderingFreeType,vtkRenderingOpenGL) -D vtkRenderingFreeType_AUTOINIT=2(vtkRenderingFreeTypeFontConfig,vtkRenderingMatplotlib) -D vtkRenderingLIC_AUTOINIT=1(vtkRenderingParallelLIC) -D vtkRenderingVolume_AUTOINIT=1(vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL) -D ___CIDR_DEFINITIONS_END -isystem /usr/local/include/opencv4 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -isystem /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ /tmp/compiler-file5852599978848190600 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -fPIC -fpch-preprocess -g -fworking-directory -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -dD
    ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7"
    ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
    ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     /usr/local/include/opencv4
     /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5
     /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets
     /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui
     /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore
     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++
     /usr/include/c++/7
     /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7
     /usr/include/c++/7/backward
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include
     /usr/local/include
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed
     /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
     /usr/include
    End of search list.
    <command-line>:0:1: error: macro names must be identifiers
```

How can I solve this problem

Comment: [ros2] tag wiki: `Please ask ROS 2 related questions on https://robotics.stackexchange.com from now on.` so you may have better luck there

Comment: See https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues?q=identifiers